# RedShift: relation does not exist

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have next data at RedShift in column "inputs":

```
[{"desc": "How many people does the video contain?", "name": "Number of People", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Only 1", "2-3", "3+"]}, {"desc": "What is the camera position?", "name": "Movement", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Fixed position", "Moving"]}, {"desc": "From which angle did you shoot the video?", "name": "Shoot Angle", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Frontal recording", "Tight angle: 10-40 degree", "Wide angle: 40-70 degree"]}, {"desc": "From which distance did you shoot the video?", "name": "Distance", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Near/Selfie", "Mid (3-6 ft)", "Far (>6 ft)"]}, {"desc": "What is the video lighting direction?", "name": "Lighting Direction", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Front lit", "Side lit", "Back lit"]}, {"desc": "What is the video background?", "name": "Background", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Outdoors", "In office", "At home", "Plain background"]}, {"desc": "What is the topic in your speech?", "name": "Topic", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Arts and Media", "Business", "Education", "Entertainment", "Food/Eating", "Nutrition", "Healthcare ", "High School Life", "Mental Health", "News", "Technology", "Morals and Ethics", "Phones and Apps", "Sports", "Science"]}
```

"inputs" is not "super" type of column.

So, I need to parse each of dict to each row.

I try to use this query:

```
SELECT JSON_PARSE(c.inputs)::super AS jp, d.desc FROM appen_collect.staticprompts AS c, jp AS d WHERE prompttype = 'input' LIMIT 10;
```

But I got an error: relation "jp" does not exist.

I don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

probably need to format as a subquery, try below:

```
select d.desc
from
(
    select json_parse(inputs)::super as jp
    from appen_collect.staticprompts
    where prompttype = 'input'
) as c, jp as d
limit 10;
```